# Xdebug does not work after installation in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug

Xdebug does not work after installation in VSCode.

```
// Output - array(1) { ["name"]=> string(4) "Sasi" }
```

where is a stylization??

I installed Xdebug step by step!
I had resigned myself:(

Answer (score 0):

just change xdebug.default_enable = off >>>on & restart Open server!